# What is the default session timeout value in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, session

What is the default session timeout value in ASP.NET?

Answer (score 24):

default is 20 minutes but you can change in web.conifg

```
<sessionState timeout="20"></sessionState>
```

Answer (score 15):

The machine.config can override the default value for the server's Session State, among others.

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\machine.config

PS. ASP.NET v3.0 and v3.5 also use the v2.0.x machine config.

Answer (score 14):

20 minutes.

Answer (score 11):

The default is 20 minutes.

Answer (score 3):

the default timeout is 20 minutes

Comment: not sure why you decided to answer this 2 years later with the same answer that 4 other people had already given. Downvoted.

Comment: same as @ThiagoSilva said.

Answer (score 1):

1. The Default Expiration Period for **Session is 20 Minutes**.
2. The Default Expiration Period for **Cookie is 30 Minutes**.
3. Maximum Size of **ViewState is 25% of Page Size**